# Plotly graph not rendered in browser when using Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, plotly, plotly-python

I have a Flask web app and the app renders a plotly graph in the web browser after a button is clicked. When I run my app, it works fine.

Now I want to dockerize this app, I have already created a DockerFile and also created a container from the image. But when rn the container and click on the button present on the web page so that a plotly graph would be rendered in the browser, I get the below error

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/io/_base_renderers.py", line 675, in open_html_in_browser
    browser = webbrowser.get(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/webbrowser.py", line 65, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

Full error here: https://zerobin.net/?aec37e9510e3132c#ysB2RZBE0GGKBBpiUQ8SJb6Wx8AptHEugiL2JsO2Y6s=

I am attaching my code for reference
DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

# EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

app.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_dropzone import Dropzone
from resume_parser_code import main

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    UPLOADED_PATH= os.path.join(basedir,'uploads'),
    DROPZONE_MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024,
    DROPZONE_TIMEOUT = 5*60*1000)

dropzone = Dropzone(app)
@app.route("/", methods=['POST','GET'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files.get('file')
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADED_PATH'],f.filename))
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/vmd_timestamp')
def vmd_timestamp():
    main()
    return render_template('vmd_timestamp.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

resume_parser_code.py

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly

def plot_graph(df):
    colors = ["#0C3B5D", "#3EC1CD", "#EF3A4C", "#FCB94D", "#336600", "#cc2900", "#9999ff", "#b366ff"]
    fig = px.bar(df, x="Score", y="Resume", color="Skill", title="Resume Skill Score",
                template = 'presentation',
                 color_discrete_sequence = colors, orientation="h", text="Score",
                hover_data={"Score": ":.s"})
    
    fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text}', textposition='auto', textfont_size=12, 
                     insidetextanchor="middle", textangle=0)

    fig.update_layout(
        yaxis={'categoryorder':'total ascending', 'tickfont': {'size': 12}, "showgrid":False, "titlefont": {"size": 18}}, 
        bargap=0.2,
        margin=dict(l=150, r=50, t=70, b=100, pad=4),
        xaxis = {"showgrid": False, 'tickfont': {'size': 14}, "titlefont": {"size": 18}},
        legend = {"font": {"size": 14}}
    )
    fig.update_yaxes(tickangle=-45)
   
    fig.show(renderer="browser", config={"displayModeBar": True, })

def main():
# df is somehow assigned
    plot_graph(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The Docker commands I use:
Build the docker image
`docker build -t flaskapp:latest .`
Run container
`docker run -p 5000:5000 flaskapp`

Comment: Meanwhile, I have found a workaround here - https://towardsdatascience.com/web-visualization-with-plotly-and-flask-3660abf9c946